# QThread Потоки ( как правильно закрыть поток )

Tags: c++, qt, многопоточность

Привет всем! накидал маленький рабочий пример за 5 минут, но возник вопрос, как правильно закрыть поток? При старте создаётся новый поток, а старый сохраняется... Возможно, что то не учёл или сделал не так. Вот исходники:

main.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
QApplication a(argc, argv);
MainWindow w;
w.show();

return a.exec();
}
```

mainwindow.cpp

```
 #include "mainwindow.h"
 #include "ui_mainwindow.h"
 #include <QDebug>
 #include <QtCore>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
QMainWindow(parent),
ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
ui->setupUi(this);
connect(this->ui->pushButton_start, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(startGUI()));
connect(this->ui->pushButton_stop, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(stopGUI()));
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::startGUI()
{

// Создание потока
QThread* thread = new QThread;
Worker* worker = new Worker();

// Передаем права владения "рабочим" классом, классу QThread.
worker->moveToThread(thread);

//connect(worker, SIGNAL(sendBool(bool)), this, SLOT(stopGUI(bool)));

// Связываем сигнал об ошибки со слотом обработки ошибок(не показан).
//connect(worker, SIGNAL(error(QString)), this, SLOT(errorHandler(QString)));

// Соединяем сигнал started потока, со слотом process "рабочего" класса, т.е. начинается выполнение нужной работы.
connect(thread, SIGNAL(started()), worker, SLOT(process()));

// Отображаем в главном потоке Gui, значения из вторичного потока
connect(worker, SIGNAL(sendNumber(int)), this, SLOT(LineEditUi(int)));

// Оповещаем поток, что нужно остановиться
connect(this, SIGNAL(sendNumberBoolStop(bool)), worker, SLOT(reciveBoolStop(bool)), Qt::DirectConnection);

// По завершению выходим из потока, и удаляем рабочий класс
connect(worker, SIGNAL(finished()), thread, SLOT(quit()));
connect(worker, SIGNAL(finished()), worker, SLOT(deleteLater()));

// Удаляем поток, после выполнения операции
connect(thread, SIGNAL(finished()), thread, SLOT(deleteLater()));

thread->start();
}

void MainWindow::LineEditUi(int number)
{
ui->lineEdit->setText(QString::number(number));
}


void MainWindow::stopGUI()
{
Stop = true;
qDebug() << Stop;
sendNumberBoolStop(Stop);
qDebug() << "sendMumberBoolStop = " << Stop;
}
```

mainwindow.h

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include "worker.h"

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
Q_OBJECT

public:
explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
~MainWindow();

bool Stop;

public slots:
void startGUI();

void stopGUI();
void LineEditUi(int number);

signals:
void sendNumberBoolStop(bool);


private:
Ui::MainWindow *ui;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

worker.cpp

```
#include "worker.h"
#include <QDebug>

Worker::Worker(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent)
{
Stop = false;
temp = 0;
}

Worker::~Worker()
{
qDebug() << "destruction Thread";
}


void Worker::process()
{
Stop = false;
if(!Stop == true)
{
    for (temp; temp <= 1000; temp++)
    {
        if(!Stop == true)
        {
        emit(sendNumber(temp));
        //ui->lineEdit->setText(QString::number(temp));
        //QCoreApplication::processEvents();
        qDebug() << temp;
        }
        else
        {
            return;
        }
    }
  }
}


void Worker::reciveBoolStop(bool Numb)
{
Stop = Numb;
qDebug() << "reciveBoolStop = " << Stop;
}
```

worker.h

```
#ifndef WORKER_H
#define WORKER_H

#include <QObject>

class Worker : public QObject
{
Q_OBJECT
public:
//Worker();
//virtual ~Worker();
explicit Worker(QObject *parent = 0);
~Worker();

bool Stop;
int temp;

signals:
void finished();
//void error(QString err);

void sendNumber(int);

public slots:
void process();

void reciveBoolStop(bool Numb);
};

#endif // WORKER_H
```

mainwindow.ui

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
<class>MainWindow</class>
<widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
<property name="geometry">
<rect>
<x>0</x>
<y>0</y>
<width>395</width>
<height>165</height>
</rect>
</property>
<property name="windowTitle">
<string>MainWindow</string>
</property>
<widget class="QWidget" name="centralWidget">
<layout class="QHBoxLayout" name="horizontalLayout_2">
<item>
 <layout class="QHBoxLayout" name="horizontalLayout">
  <item>
   <widget class="QLineEdit" name="lineEdit"/>
  </item>
  <item>
   <widget class="QPushButton" name="pushButton_start">
    <property name="text">
     <string>Start</string>
    </property>
   </widget>
  </item>
  <item>
   <widget class="QPushButton" name="pushButton_stop">
    <property name="text">
     <string>Stop</string>
    </property>
   </widget>
  </item>
 </layout>
</item>
</layout>
</widget>
<widget class="QMenuBar" name="menuBar">
<property name="geometry">
<rect>
 <x>0</x>
 <y>0</y>
 <width>395</width>
 <height>21</height>
</rect>
</property>
</widget>
<widget class="QToolBar" name="mainToolBar">
<attribute name="toolBarArea">
<enum>TopToolBarArea</enum>
</attribute>
<attribute name="toolBarBreak">
<bool>false</bool>
</attribute>
</widget>
<widget class="QStatusBar" name="statusBar"/>
</widget>
<layoutdefault spacing="6" margin="11"/>
<resources/>
<connections/>
</ui>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

В приведенном коде не испускается сигнал `Worker::finished`, следовательно поток не понимает, что ему нужно остановиться. Испустить сигнал нужно на выходе из функции `Worker::process`.

Добавлю, что для задачи единоразово запустить какой-то процесс в отдельном потоке лучше подойдет `QtConcurrent::run`

```
void MainWindow::startGUI()
{
    Worker* worker = new Worker();

    // Отображаем в главном потоке Gui, значения из вторичного потока
    connect(worker, SIGNAL(sendNumber(int)), this, SLOT(LineEditUi(int)));

    // Оповещаем поток, что нужно остановиться
    connect(this, SIGNAL(sendNumberBoolStop(bool)), worker, SLOT(reciveBoolStop(bool)), Qt::DirectConnection);

    //Запланируем удаление воркера после окончания расчета
    connect(worker,SIGNAL(finished()), worker,SLOT(deleteLater()));
    QtConcurrent::run(worker,&Worker::process);
}
```

Comment: Спасибо тебе добавил в Worker::process emit finished(); и что бы по кнопке stop тоже поток завершался добавил emit finished(); и все заработало!) , а как данный пример будет выглядить с QtConcurrent::run?

Comment: Все разобрался, спасибо еще раз) такой подход тоже работает