# Как "выключить" поток?

Tags: c++, qt, многопоточность, qt5

По моей задумке, я создаю вектор потоков, запускаю его на нажатие CheckBox-а, на  отжатие CheckBox-а происходит завершение потока.

На деле при нажатии CheckBox-а он запускает отдельный поток, НО при отжатии  CheckBox-а **не отрабатывается** завершение потока.

Что я делаю не так ??

Вот кусок кода где происходит данное действо:

```
void MainWindow::start_sending(bool Value)
{
    NewsThread *two_cl = new NewsThread(); // инициализируем второй класс

    if (test_checkbox_old == 0)
    {
        test_checkbox_old = test_checkbox.length();
        qDebug() << "test_checkbox_old" <<test_checkbox_old ;
        seting_clear(test_checkbox_old);
    }
    if (test_checkbox_old != test_checkbox.length())
    {
        qDebug() << "!test_checkbox_old" <<test_checkbox_old ;
        seting_clear(test_checkbox_old, test_checkbox.length());
        test_checkbox_old = test_checkbox.length();
    }

    for(int i =0; i< test_checkbox.length();i++)
    {
        if (Value == true)
        {
            if(test_checkbox[i]->isChecked() == true)
            {
                if(togled_checked_sensor[i] == 0)
                {
                    qDebug() << " светлая сторона  " <<  i;
                    togled_checked_sensor[i] = 1;
                    connect(test_checkbox[i], SIGNAL(stateChanged(int, QString, int)), two_cl , SLOT(run_NEW(int, QString, int)));// от кого, "реакция", кому, "выполнение"

                    two_cl->moveToThread(vector_thread[i]);
                    vector_thread[i]->start();
                }
            }
        }
        // обратный метод очистки
        if(Value == false)
        {
            if(test_checkbox[i]->isChecked() == false)
            {
                if(togled_checked_sensor[i] == 1)
                {
                    togled_checked_sensor[i] = 0;
                    qDebug() << " темная сторона  " <<  i;
//                    vector_thread[i]->quit(); // чёт не работает
                    vector_thread[i]->exit(); // чет тоже не работает
                }
            }
        }
    }

void MainWindow::seting_clear(int i)
{
    for (int f =0 ; f<i; f++)
    {
        thread = new QThread(); // инициализ класс потока из за того что
        vector_thread.append(thread);
        qDebug() << " f :" << f;

    }
}
void MainWindow::seting_clear(int i, int f)
{
    f = f-i;
    for(int a =0; a<f;a++)
    {
        thread = new QThread();
        vector_thread.append(thread);
        qDebug() << " a :" << a;

    }
}
```

а вот где "работает" циклом поток

```
     void NewsThread::run_NEW(int i, QString str, int f)
    {

        // -- вот тут механизм гетеров сетеров
        Foo *FO = new Foo();
        FO->setData(155);

        for(;;){ // вечный цикл
        if( QThread::currentThread()->isInterruptionRequested()  )
        {
            for (int i=0; i<500; i++)
            {
                qDebug()<< "Число :" << i <<"номер \"потока\" :" << str ;
                qDebug()<< "Тут переменная котрая задаётся в маинвиндовс класе переходит в майчекбокс и возвращаеться сюда: "  ;
                qDebug()<< "QThread::currentThreadId() : "<< QThread::currentThreadId();
                 qDebug()<< "Число переданное из майчекбокс :" << f <<" FO.getData: " << FO->getData() ;
                usleep(100);
             }
          }
      }
    }
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [QThread Потоки ( как правильно закрыть поток )](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/543639/qthread-%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%82%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%ba%d1%80%d1%8b%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%82%d0%be%d0%ba)

Comment: вызовете для потока метод `requestInterruption`, в функции, которая крутится внутри потока проверяйте для текущего потока не было ли запрошено прерывание выполнения, и тогда выходите (while (!QThread::thisThread()->interruptionIsRequested()){...}). После request interruption можно добавить wait(), если нужно дождаться пока поток завершится. А вообще есть `QThreadPool` и `Qt Concurrent`

Comment: @vegorov дополнил код и поставил функцию которая работает в отдельном потоке. Извините но я так и не понял что надо сделать что бы выйти из потока.

Comment: @timob256 Нужно чтобы метод run_NEW завершился. Например, по условию `QThread::currentThread->interruptionIsRequested`

Comment: @timob256 А у Вас бесконечный цикл с задержкой

Comment: @vegorov  добавил  `QThread::currentThread()->isInterruptionRequested() == true ` и отказался от вечного цикла, но всё равно не отрабатывает `vector_thread[i]->exit()`     и               `vector_thread[i]->quit()`

Comment: @timob256 а вы сделайте vector_thread[i]->requestInterruption() перед quit или exit()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пользователь **@vegorov** дал ответ.

Надо было отказаться от вечного цикла, и воспользоваться функцией `requestInterruption()`

Вот код который изменился (всё остальное осталось прежним)

```
    // обратный метод очистки
    if(Value == false)
    {
        if(test_checkbox[i]->isChecked() == false)
        {
            if(togled_checked_sensor[i] == 1)
            {
                togled_checked_sensor[i] = 0;
                qDebug() << " темная сторона  " <<  i;
                //  vector_thread[i]->quit();
                vector_thread[i]->requestInterruption(); // !!! НОВЫЙ ДОБАВЛЕННЫЙ КОД 
                vector_thread[i]->exit();
            }
        }
    }
```

А  вот функция вызова

```
void NewsThread::run_NEW(int i, QString str, int f)
{

    // -- вот тут механизм гетеров сетеров
    Foo *FO = new Foo();
    FO->setData(155);
    // Отказался от вечного цикла  
    for(int i=0; i<500; i++) 
    {
        qDebug()<< "Число :" << i <<"номер \"потока\" :" << str ;
        qDebug()<< "QThread::currentThreadId() : "<< QThread::currentThreadId();
         qDebug()<< "Число переданное из майчекбокс :" << f <<" FO.getData: " << FO->getData() ;
        usleep(100);

        if (i == 499)
        {
            if( QThread::currentThread()->isInterruptionRequested() == true ) // !!! НОВЫЙ ДОБАВЛЕННЫЙ КОД
            {
                qDebug() << " tyt";
                return;
            }
                else
                i = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Посмотрите в сторону `QThreadPool` и [QConcurent::run](http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qtconcurrentrun.html). Создавая вручную кучу потоков вы только тратите ресурсы системы

Comment: @vegorov я попробовал освоить фраемворк `QConcurent` и воспользоваться методом  `QConcurent::run`  у меня даже запустить его не получилось, я связываю такой результат  с моим уровнем интеллекта.