# Как переключать QStackedWidget, вовремя расчётов, на прелоадер?

Tags: c++, linux, windows, qt, qwidget

У меня есть QStackedWidget, у него есть три области:

1 Область, эктивации расчётов `(ui->stackedWidgetWaterSurface->setCurrentIndex(0);)`:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
2 Область, прелоадер `(ui->stackedWidgetWaterSurface->setCurrentIndex(1);)`:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
3 Область, результат расчётов `(ui->stackedWidgetWaterSurface->setCurrentIndex(2);)`:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Когда я нажимаю кнопку Расчёт, выполняется следующий код:

```
void PollutionZoneWidget::clickedCalculation()
{
    ui->stackedWidgetWaterSurface->setCurrentIndex(1); //не срабатывает
    if (setTimeValue()==true)
    {
        if (setTotalVolume()==true)
        {

            SurfaceCalculation(1,100,1,1);
            OutputResults();
            ui->stackedWidgetWaterSurface->setCurrentIndex(2);
        }
    }
}
```

Но строчка :`ui->stackedWidgetWaterSurface->setCurrentIndex(1);` не срабатывает, прелоадер не появляется. Когда только про извёлся расчёт показывается результат `ui->stackedWidgetWaterSurface->setCurrentIndex(2);`
Может кто подскажет,другой виджет Qt, для этих целей или поможет изменить код для того чтоб показывался прелоадер во время расчётов ?

Comment: обычно чтобы, что-то произошло надо дать поработать циклу обработки сообщений, т.е. после setCurrentIndex, надо выполнить qApp->processEvents(QEventLoop::ExcludeUserInputEvents);

Comment: @Pavel Gridin да сработало ! Только анимация не проигрывается в gif // Как ещё запустить анимацию ?

Comment: для анимации, наверное надо всё время крутить processEvents, лучше правда потоками делайте

Answer (score 3, accepted):

На самом деле все срабатывает как надо, просто так как вы крутите расчет в основном потоке, гуй не реагирует на изменения, пока не будет произведен выход из вашего метода `clickedCalculation()`.

Выходов два:

1. Можно вручную дернуть `QApplication::processEvents` после задания индекса страницы, но это дурной тон
2. Вынести расчет в отдельный поток, как положено и общаться сигналами

Comment: Можно пример кода, который выносит расчет в отдельный поток? Я просто думаю не правильно работаю с потоками

Comment: посмотрите например вот здесь https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/543639/qthread-Потоки-как-правильно-закрыть-поток/543651#543651

Comment: ещё http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/thread-basics.html#example-1-using-the-thread-pool

Comment: спасибо , в прошлый раз меня ругали. Когда я криво написал потоки

Comment: @Bearded Beaver Из потока можно вернуть данные и остановить выполнение функции, когда подсчёт будет закончен, снова возобновить  выполнение функции?

Comment: У меня сейчас так что быстро проскакивает подсчёты и выводит результаты. Только вот площадь не выводит так как она в потоке считается

Comment: Можно, используйте сигналы для общения между потоком счета и основным потоком

Comment: @Bearded Beaver спасибо большое разобрался с потоком . Теперь и анимация проигрывается и обрабатывается в потоке.